# Access member variables of derived class object pointed to by a pointer to its base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have one base class and two classes derived from it. I have several virtual functions in the base class so I create a pointer to the base class and use this pointer to access these methods.

Now I want to access member variable of derived class (this variable is not present in the base class) using the pointer to base class which points to a derived class object.

*Can this be done? Should this be done?*

Answer (score 7):

Why do you want to access the derived class' interface? When you use polymorphism, you shouldn't need to care about what's behind a base class reference/pointer. **If you do, then that's usually a hint at a design flaw.**

What you are trying to do is a "switch-on-type". ("If behind `B*` is a `D1` object, do this, otherwise do that".) A switch-on-type is circumventing polymorphism and a bad sign.

*Note: There is a way to do this (`dynamic_cast`), but for the reasons mentioned above I consider this bad practice and won't elaborate on it.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, but it is not recommended. You can use dynamic_cast to cast the base class pointer to the derived class pointer and get the variables in the derived class.

For example, if you have a base clas called Base and two derived classes Derived1 and Derived2, and if you have `Base* p` pointer then you can do:

```
Derived1* d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a virtual function, that would act accordingly in each of the classes, and in the place where you actually "need" to access the variable - call that function. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just move that variable to the base class. The only case when Base class need to call methods (or to use variables) of Derived class is [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) when it implements static polymorphism. In other cases it looks like bad design.